# test a callback to an outside function with in setInterval() using MochaJS

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, setinterval, sinon

I need to test the call to the `destroyTask()` with in the `setInterval()` The `setInterval()` compares two time stamps and them calls the `destroyTask()` when they current time is equal to the `finishTime`

```
 async jobTimeout() {
    if (!this.timeout || !this.timeunits) return;
    const startTime = moment();
    const finishTime = moment().add(this.timeout, this.timeunits);
    // console.log('Duration - ', this.timeout, ' ' ,this.timeunits);

    console.log(`Start Time: ${startTime}`);
    console.log(`Finish Time: ${finishTime}`);

    this._timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(moment());
      if (moment().isAfter(finishTime)) {
        console.log("The task didn't finish in time. ", this.destroyTask());
        clearInterval(this._timer); // the clearInterval() method clears a timer set with the setInterval() method
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I'm using sinon to spy on two function and fake timers to overwrite `setInterval`. My test case is bellow:

```
 describe('Generic Setup', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Overwrite the global timer functions (setTimeout, setInterval) with Sinon fakes
      this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      // Restore the global timer functions to their native implementations
      this.clock.restore();
    });

    it('Job Should Timeout After Specified Duration', async () => {
      const task = new TASK(taskData, done);
      const result = sinon.spy(await task.jobTimeout());
      const destroyTask = sinon.spy(await task.destroyTask());

      setInterval(result, 1000);

      this.clock.tick(4000);
      expect(destroyTask).to.not.have.been.called;

      this.clock.tick(1000);
      expect(destroyTask).to.have.been.called;
    });
  });
```

I receive the following error `TypeError: this.done is not a function`. I think it's caused by `destroyTask`, but it is a function.

```
async destroyTask() {
    // TODO cleanup tmp directory - might want to collect stat on error
    clearInterval(this._timer);
    this.done();
  }
```

What can be the cause? Is it possible to test callback to outside function with in another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify a few things. I've changed the spy call, increased the second `this.clock.tick()` to `2000` and had to give a custom `done` function in class instantiation.

```
  describe('Generic Setup', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Overwrite the global timer functions (setTimeout, setInterval) with Sinon fakes
      this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      // Restore the global timer functions to their native implementations
      this.clock.restore();
    });

    it('Job Should Timeout After Specified Duration', async () => {
      const task = new TASK(taskData, () => {});

      task.jobTimeout();

      const destroyTaskSpy = sinon.spy(task, 'destroyTask');

      this.clock.tick(4000);
      expect(destroyTaskSpy).to.not.have.been.called;

      this.clock.tick(2000);
      expect(destroyTaskSpy).to.have.been.called;

      // Remove the spy to prevent future errors
      destroyTaskSpy.restore();
    });
  });
```